# Find the value where two normal distributions have equal probability.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Having difficulty with these questions from my one of my modules

In a certain population women have weights which are Normally distributed with a
mean of 50kg and a standard deviation of 5kg. Men have weights which are
Normally distributed with a mean of 70kg and a standard deviation of 10kg.

A) Find a weight w to the nearest 0.1kg such that both men and women would have an
equal probability of having a weight between w and w+1 kg.

B) How many points of equal probability are there?

Comment: Is the proportion of men and woman 50/50?

Comment: To start, represent $w = 70+10k_1$ and $w+1 = 70+10k_2$. This allows you to solve for $k_1,k_2$. You want the difference in probabilities for these $z$-scores to be equal to the difference in probabilities between $z$-scores of $l_1,l_2$ where $w=50+5l_1$ and $w+1=50+5l_2$. Something to that effect.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+for+w:+Int%5Be%5E(-x%5E2),%7Bx,(w-70)%2F10,(w-69)%2F10%7D%5D+%3D+Int%5Be%5E(-x%5E2),%7Bx,(w-50)%2F5,(w-49)%2F5%7D%5D

Wolframalpha finds two solutions.